# How to create a image browser with wxpython

Tags: image-processing, wxpython

i looking for a way to design a gui with wxpython that browse pictures.i'm able to display images individually like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNtyf.png

but just want to have the ability to see the images as thumbnails by the side. kinda like this.

http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/extra/images/thumbnails.png

hope you guys can provide some tips and help on this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of the ThumbNailCtrl widget. You can read more about it at the following:

- http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl-module.html

It's also in the wxPython demo package.

I wrote a simple image viewer too, although it doesn't do thumbnails at this time. You can read about that here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/

Comment: hi mike, i've saw your example and it is the building foundation for my gui in fact. now i can thank you in person for having such a great tutorial. i will look at thumbnailctrl-module. thank you.

Comment: No problem. I hope it helps.